# Why do I have a declaration error showing Identifier not found or not unique

Tags: error, declaration

I am writing the smart contract for NFT. it is my first one. it is showing the DeclarationError as below and I do not know how to solve it. Could you please kindly help me? Thank you

from solidity:

```
DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
 --> contracts/Clokkworky.sol:8:28:
  |
8 |     contract Clokkworky is ERC721, Ownable {

  |                            ^^^^^^
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the contracts you are using.

For `ERC721` it will be something like this;

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.5.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
```

I'll leave as homework to find how to do the same for `Ownable`. Just be sure to use the same release, the `v4.5.0` in the URL.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and see the result.